# Is it possible to sort a stack using merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

A stack can be implemented as a linked list.
Linked lists can be sorted using merge sort:
O(n log n) time
O(n) space

It makes sense to be able to sort a stack using merge sort.

If that's the case, what would the code look like?

(after a quick search on the web, I only found brute force algorithms O(n^2))

Comment: Can you only use the pop() and push() methods? Or do you look at the stack as a glass box, and you can manipulate the internals as you wish?

Comment: @amit I think first thing. Otherwise - what's the difference with array (in general) ?

Comment: pop, push, peek, isEmpty are only allowed

Comment: Does this help:- http://www.cs.utep.edu/ofuentes/cs2302/fall11/nonRecursiveMergesort.txt ?

Comment: it looks like an implementation for arrays, we have a stack here

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, but a stack defines an order, last in, first out. sorting it will make it, well - not a stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we can. The trick is understanding that when the stack is sorted, the head is the largest element - and we want to iterate it from lower to higher We can reverse a stack however in O(n).

```
reverse(stack):
   s <- new stack
   while stack.isEmpty() == false:
       s.push(stack.pop)
   return s
```

Now, using it, and assuming you can use size() as well, it is fairly easy to implement and is a standard for most stack implementation - we can implement a merge sort:

**Pseudo code:**

```
mergeSort(stack):
   if stack.isEmpty():
       return stack
   s1 <- new stack
   s2 <- new stack
   //   O(n):
   while s1.size() < stack.size():
        s1.push(stack.pop())
   while (stack.isEmpty() == false):
        s2.push(stack.pop())           
   mergeSort(s1) //half the size of stack
   mergeSort(s2) //half the size of stack
   //head of s1 and s2 is the largest element
   s1 <- s1.reverse() //easily implemented in O(n)
   s2 <- s2.reverse()
   //now head of s1 and s2 is the smallest element
   while (s1.isEmpty() == false and s2.isEmpty() == false):
        if (s1.peek() < s2.peek()):
            stack.push(s1.pop())
         else:
            stack.push(s2.pop())
   //the 'tail' of one stack:
   while (s1.isEmpty() == false):
         stack.push(s1.pop())
   while (s2.isEmpty() == false):
         stack.push(s2.pop())
   //head is the largest, stacks are sorted
   return stack
```

**Correctness:**

Base: The stop clause is an empty stack, which is sorted.

Hypothesis: s1 and s2 are sorted.

Step: After reversing, s1 and s2 are basically traversed in the order of lower->higher, in sorted area when taking off elements using the pop() method. Since we always insert the smaller element from each stack, and we are traversing each stack from low to high - we get that the resulting stack is in order.

**Complexity:**

Excluding recursive calls, each step is `O(stack.size()) = O(n)`. This is the same behavior as regular merge sort, and the rest of the complexity follows the same steps of original merge sort to get `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe i miss the point but i would do it this way:

```
void mergesortStack(Stack input) {
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    Stack stackLeft = new Stack();
    Stack stackRight = new Stack();

    // split
    while (!input.isEmpty()) {
        stackLeft.push(input.pop());
        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            stackRight.push(input.pop());
        }
    }

    // recurse
    if (!stackLeft.isEmpty() && !stackRight.isEmpty()) {
        mergesortStack(stackLeft);
        mergesortStack(stackRight);
    }

    // merge
    Stack tmpStack = new Stack();
    while (!stackLeft.isEmpty() || !stackRight.isEmpty()) {
        if (stackLeft.isEmpty()) {
            tmpStack.push(stackRight.pop());
        } else if (stackRight.isEmpty()) {
            tmpStack.push(stackLeft.pop());
            // set an appropriate compare method
        } else if (stackLeft.peek().compareTo(stackRight.peek()) >= 0) {
            tmpStack.push(stackLeft.pop());
        } else {
            tmpStack.push(stackRight.pop());
        }
    }

    // reverse stack
    while (!tmpStack.isEmpty()) {
        input.push(tmpStack.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing something very important here. assuming correctness of the recursive call, each smaller stack will have its head as maximal. But you are going to push it first. It will cause the stack to be in the wrong order - since the head will no longer be the largest element. This contradicts the correctness of the algorithm. It can be solved easily -but it is the most important aspect in this question, IMO.

Comment: the isEmpty checks in recurse phase appear to be redundant